# How can I get the number of collaborators in someone else's GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I tried to use the number of committers who merged pull requests into the master branch. However, I cannot consider the reject action.

In GitHub, is there a way I can see the number of collaborators within someone else's repository?

Answer (score 12):

The GitHub API v3 has an endpoint for [listing collaborators](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#list-collaborators):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators
```

To use it, you need to authenticate, and you have to be one of those collaborators or you'd see this:

```json
{
  "message": "Must have push access to view repository collaborators.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

---

I've noticed that when you go to the Issues section of a repository and filter by author or assignee, you get [a drop-down listing the repository's collaborators](https://help.github.com/articles/filtering-issues-and-pull-requests-by-assignees/). The HTML content of this drop-down is loaded on demand, in a separate GET request, for example:

```
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/show_menu_content?partial=issues/filters/authors_content
```

- This is a *hack*. The URL is obviously not intended for programmatic consumption. Output is HTML, which may change. There's no warranty: use at your own risk.
- This URL works for everyone, you don't even need to be logged into GitHub. If you're logged in, your account will appear first in the list.
- This URL works even on repositories with Issues disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need. So, i went and found the details of all PushEvent, CreateEvent and PullRequestEvent made on the master branch of the repository from githubarchive database hosted on google bigquery. From this, I could get a conservative estimate of all the users who are collaborators. Every PullRequestEvent that is merged results in a push event with the name of the collaborator who merged the request. However, if a PullRequestEvent is rejected, I had to look at who closed the PullRequest and if it is not the user that originally created the pull request then that person is also a collaborator. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but this is all I could think off.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - wanted to find number of contributors but I am not a contributor myself. I ended up just doing a get request to the repo's home page and scraping for number of contributors. Using python:

```
html = requests.get("https://github.com" + js_repo)
e = PyQuery(html.content)
links = e('li')
for link in links:
    if("contributors" in PyQuery(link).html()):
        items = PyQuery(link).items('span')
        for i in items:
            if "Fetching" in str(i):
                contributors = float('nan')
                break
            locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 
            contributors = locale.atoi(i.text())
            print(contributors)
```

Answer (score -1):

From your repository page, click on the `Settings` tab, then `Collaborators`.

URL example

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo name>/settings/collaboration
```

To check who has contributed to a repository that you do not own, you can can go to the repo, click `Graphs`, then click `Members`.

URL example

```
https://github.com/<owner username>/<repo name>/network/members
```

Comment: I thought your answer can work in my repository. How can I get in others' repo?

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I didn't understand the question.